# Angular promise return

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

I have an Angular Service and I want to return a promise with a Typed Array but i'm allways getting this error: src/app/city.service.ts(52,22): error TS2339: Property 'places' does not exist on type 'CityService'.
I have no idea of what I am doing wrong.

```
getPlace(coordinates : Coordinates) {
//    var places : Array<Place> = [];


let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/place/',  {params: coordinates})
      .toPromise()
      .then(

          res => { // Success
             var places: Array<Place>;

            this.places = res.results.map(item => {
              var place = new Place();
              place.place_id = item.place_id;
              place.name = item.name;
              place.vicinity = item.vicinity;
              place.coordinates = new Coordinates();
              place.coordinates.latitude = item.geometry.location.lat;
              place.coordinates.longitude = item.geometry.location.lng;
              return place;
            });

            resolve(this.places);
          },
          msg => { // Error
            reject(msg);
          }
      );
});
return promise;
}
```

Comment: Does your service have a field called `places`, or should your function be using `places` instead of `this.places`?

Comment: Why did you manually create an observable that resolve when the inner http resolve and reject when the inner reject? Why don't you juste use the http promise?

Comment: @NoémiSalaün rookie mistake

Comment: @NoémiSalaün Can I use the inner http resolve if I dont want to create an observable?  https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-promises/

Comment: @John See my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the comment is pretty correct, variables that are not the part of a service, and were declared inside functions must be called without this keyword.

```
 places = res.results.map ....
```

Comment: Thank you. I only have one error more here :  places = res.results.map   ....error TS2339: Property 'results' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Answer (score 1):

## This is a secondary answer, just about the unnecessary promise creation

This give the same result, without the need to manually create a new Promise which resolve when the inner promise resolve. It results in less code boilerplate and better readability.

```
getPlace(coordinates : Coordinates) {

    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/place/',  {params: coordinates})
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => {
            var places: Place[];

            places = res.results.map(item => {
              var place = new Place();
              place.place_id = item.place_id;
              place.name = item.name;
              place.vicinity = item.vicinity;
              place.coordinates = new Coordinates();
              place.coordinates.latitude = item.geometry.location.lat;
              place.coordinates.longitude = item.geometry.location.lng;
              return place;
            });

            return places;
        });

}
```

Comment: now I have this error: ERROR in src/app/city.service.ts(58,28): error TS2339: Property 'results' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: I have these imports: mport { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';


import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: There is maybe a typo in my example, because I haven't changed any logic on this part :/

Comment: I will figure it out. Thanks a lot for your help!